# Discrete Math - Axiom Description / Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm having a bit of difficulty in understanding axiomatic descriptions (and set theory in general).

One of the questions I have is providing an axiomatic description for a set that contains only odd integers.

My current answer is:

$\forall x ,(2n + 1)$ where n is a Natural Number

Apologies for the syntax, I couldn't work out how to include the proper symbols.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. I'll amend that right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be described as the set $X = \{2x+1,\;x\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: Odd integers should include all negative odd integers as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Regret my apologies, fixed

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks. I didn't pick up on the negative odd integers, slipped my mind. I appreciate the quick response.

Comment: Just for clarification, does that statement cover all elements within the set?  Say, P is a set with all elements being odd integers, 

P = $\forall x$ = {2x+1,x∈Z}

Comment: Yes, that statement covers all elements within the set. I don't really like the way you describe P. You might want to describe the set as $ P = \{2x+1 : x∈\mathbb{Z}\}$.

Comment: Thanks heaps. 

I'm a bit rusty and getting back into learning it all again, the last time I did discrete math was easily 4 years ago. Much appreciated.